# truncating file names

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a folder that has a number of files all of a similar form as:

```
Dropkick Murphys - 01 - Walk Away.mp3
Dropkick Murphys - 02 - Workers Song.mp3
```

And so forth...

I want to convert them all so that they appear as:

```
01 - Walk Away.mp3
02 - Workers Song.mp3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you only trying to remove Dropkick Murphys? or are you trying to rename thousands of songs to not include the artist? There are plenty of file renamers for mp3 files based on id3 tags.

Comment: @Falmarri: It would be nice to know the generalized solution as well, because this scenario does occur with some frequency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under Ubuntu or Debian, it is simply:

```
rename 's/Dropkick Murphys - //' *mp3
```

Comment: And sometimes `prename` on other systems.

Comment: Oh, excellent; Gentoo has `rename` too and I've never used it. Although the syntax on Gentoo is `rename from to filename...`

Comment: @Michael: This is a different rename, please see the comment of ephemient, try prename.

Comment: There's no prename on my system. Oh well

Comment: I found the source code here: http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt found on this site http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal

Answer (score 5):

Pick one.

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "${i#* - }"; done
for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "${i:19}"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop to loop over the files you want to modify. `${var/from/to}` will replace the first occurrence of `from` with `to` in `$var`, so `${var/Dropkick Murphys - /}` will replace "Dropkick Murphys - " with nothing:

```
for i in "Dropkick Murphys - "*; do
    mv "$i" "${i/Dropkick Murphys - /}"    
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/^Dropkick Murphys - //')"; done`

or, more general, to remove first 3 space-delimited words from a file name

`echo $i | cut -d' ' -f4-`

Comment: Actually, the `cut` is ill-advised.  A regexp scanning for `-` would fit better here.  Tip: don't run commands you given before you understand what is going to happen and/or dry-run things using `echo mv ...` or smt. like that before running for reals.

Comment: Ty this is what I needed because the begging of my files were all different (ex blahblah 20.mp3.  I basically used for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "t$(echo $i | cut -d' ' -f2-)"; done then the command rename "t" "the title" *.mp3 to set the name

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory zsh answer:

```
autoload zmv
zmv 'Dropkick Murphys - (*.mp3)' '$1'
```

Variants, to do the renaming for all artist names. Note that the first command takes the longest match of the first `*`, e.g. it will rename `Dropkick Murphys - 01 - Walk Away - concert.mp3` to `Walk Away - concert.mp3`.

```
zmv '* - (* - *.mp3)' '$1'
zmv '*.mp3' '${f#* - }'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `rename.ul` command (I guess by default in Ubuntu). It gives you a simple way to rename files

Syntax:

```
$ rename from to file...
```