# Truncating a filename on Mac

Tags: bash, mv

I have a directory with 1000s of files named such as

```
2019-07-21-17-50-06 - 123 - abc - xyz.zzz
```

and I only need the leftmost 19 characters, i.e. the date and time.

There's no rename command on Mac, so looking around I found that the mv command could also work, eg from here [truncating file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/truncating-file-names) which gives me this

```
for i in *.mp3; do mv "$i" "${i:19}"; done
```

but I think it trims from the right, not the left.

How do I change this command to keep the 19 leftmost characters plus the suffix?

Thanks!

Comment: Install Larry Wall's rename, it is written in perl, so you you will need the perl runtime.

Comment: I wonder why people post answers as comments..

Answer (score 3):

`${i:19}` is the substring starting from the 19th (well, 20th - 0-indexing at work) character. A substring of 19 characters from the start is `${i:0:19}`.

If all files have 19 characters before the extension:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i:0:19}.${i##*.}"; done
```

`${i##*.}` strips everything up to (and including) the last `.` in the filename, leaving just the extension.

Perl rename is available from Homebrew:

```
% brew info rename
rename: stable 1.600 (bottled), HEAD
Perl-powered file rename script with many helpful built-ins
http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename
```

Comment: thanks - works great! Upvote added

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${i%% - *}` to remove everything starting from the first occurence of `-`.